# How to hanlde cell click

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I have tablewcontroller. In tableview cell i add other tables with delegates and datasource in tableviewcontroller. I can set different datasource for each table, but i can't hanlde cell didSelect event in my added tables. This is my code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    if tableView==self.category1Table{
        return category1Data.count
    }else if tableView==self.category2Table{
        return category2Data.count
    }else if tableView==self.category3Table{
        return category3Data.count
    }
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if tableView==self.category1Table{
        let cell=tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "category1Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text=category1Data[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.textColor=UIColor.white
        cell.textLabel?.font=UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 15)
        return cell
    }else if tableView==self.category2Table{
        let cell=tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "category2Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text=category2Data[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.textColor=UIColor.white
        cell.textLabel?.font=UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 15)
        return cell
    }else if tableView==self.category3Table{
        let cell=tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "category3Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text=category3Data[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.textColor=UIColor.white
        cell.textLabel?.font=UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 15)
        return cell
    }
    return mainInformationCell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if tableView==self.category1Table{
        cell.backgroundColor=UIColor.clear
    }else if tableView==self.category2Table{
        cell.backgroundColor=UIColor.clear
    }else if tableView==self.category3Table{
        cell.backgroundColor=UIColor.clear
    }else{
        cell.backgroundColor=UIColor.clear
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(indexPath.row)
    if tableView==self.category1Table{
        category1Btn.setTitle(category1Data[indexPath.row], for: .normal)
        category1Btn.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
    }else if tableView==self.category2Table{
        category2Btn.setTitle(category2Data[indexPath.row], for: .normal)
        category2Btn.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
    }else if tableView==self.category3Table{
        category3Btn.setTitle(category3Data[indexPath.row], for: .normal)
        category3Btn.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
    }
}
```

How i can do this?

Comment: What do you mean not able to handle it. Can you tell us what is going wrong or if the `didSelectRowAt` getting called.

Comment: There are no error. It just doing nothing when cell click,but i want to that it to do something. Why it doing nothing?

Comment: Have you used the debugger to see what is happening? Is your `didSelectRowAt` method being called? If so, then what happens inside that method?

Comment: `UITableViewDelegate` is not set.

Comment: With the help of UITableViewDelegate you can handle these stuff